# Sweave .rnw files won't produce a pdf in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, sweave

everyone,

Everytime I try to compile a PDF on Rstudio using Sweave, I get this error:

> Running pdflatex.exe on PS1.tex...failed Error running
> C:/PROGRA~1/MikText/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code
> -1073740791)

I have reinstalled many times MikText. I've changed the Global settings to weave files using knitr, and I changed the MikText console to install packages on the fly.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66285654/error-running-pdflatex-from-rstudio-cant-compile-pdfs-since-updating and also to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582041/r-sweave-does-not-compile-to-pdf (uninstall MikTex and install MiKTeX64-2.9.7269-basic).